# C# regex takes very long under certain conditions

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to check a string with a regex.
Roughly, the regex can be described as follows:

- The string can start with one '/'
- The string must then be followed by a letter or number
- Then the characters . - _ can be used but must be followed by at least one letter or number
- This block of rules can be used multiple times

Examples:

- /abcd/ga-b1.2.3.4/eeee.abc
- 012345678901234.aaa

The regex is:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^(/{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}(([\.\-_]{1,})[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}){0,}){0,}$")
```

This regex works fine but has one problem. When I add a `_` at the end of the string I want to check the check procedure takes suddenly really long:
E.g. "012345678901234.aaa_" takes about 15s (using a unit test to test).
"012345678901234.aaa" just takes about 150ms.

I have figured out that the last `{0,}` (which allows the block of the described rules to be used multiple times) affects this. Removing it makes it as quick as omitting the `_` but lets the regex engine stop after finding the first match. This is not what I want.

This last `{0,}` is basically a global search. I use `regex.IsMatch()` to figure out whether the input path is correct. Using `regex.Matches()` is only a workaround here because I don't know how many collection entries I should expect. I could figure it out but I prefer the elegant regex solution.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with my regex that it takes so long?

In [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) the string "012345678901234.aaa_" works as expected - without the performance penalty:

```
/^(\/{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}(([\.\-_]{1,})[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}){0,}){0,}/g
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, this sounds like catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: Sure it is a catastrophic backtracking. Use `"^/?[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[/._-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$"`.